# How to drop a Unique Constraint set on a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have created a table below,
"CREATE TABLE UNIQ(NUM INT UNIQUE, NAMES VARCHAR(10))"

Now i want to drop/disable the UNIQUE constraint set on NUM column. 
How to do this with Query..?

I googled and got to know that, if i am giving constraint name while creating table, then using that name i can easily drop the contraint.

EX:
CREATE TABLE UNIQ(NUM INT CONSTRAINT CONTR_NAME UNIQUE, NAMES VARCHAR(10))

For dropping constraint.,
ALTER TABLE UNIQ DROP CONSTRAINT CONTR_NAME

Thanks in advance.. :)

Thanks

Mahesh

Comment: Even if you have not specified the name, the constraint is named somehow. Find out the name and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE UNIQ
DROP CONSTRAINT [name of constraint]
```

The below query should help you find the name of the constraint

```
SELECT
    o.name AS ConstraintName,
    c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.objects p
        ON o.parent_object_id = p.object_id
    JOIN sys.columns c
        ON c.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE o.type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
AND p.Name = 'UNIQ'
```

Comment: OK, if you provided an answer, provide a way to finding the constraint name before you get downvoted. People here are very fast in downvoting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName VARCHAR(256)
SET @ConstraintName = (
     SELECT             obj.name
     FROM               sys.columns col 

     LEFT OUTER JOIN    sys.objects obj 
     ON                 obj.object_id = col.default_object_id 
     AND                obj.type = 'UQ' 

     WHERE              col.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName') 
     AND                obj.name IS NOT NULL
     AND                col.name = 'ColunmName'
)   

IF(@ConstraintName IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+@ConstraintName+']')
END
```

Comment: Executing successfully but not disabling the Constraint

Comment: Ideally it should disable. Try to print the `ConstraintName` 
See if its working or not.
After that You can delete it manually by writing a query
`ALTER TABLE [TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+@ConstraintName+']'`